# How to read datasource of a Kendo DropDownList only once?

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, grid, load, readonly

(MVC Razor) So on my page I have a *Kendo grid* which contains a *DropDownList* within a certain column. Now I don't want to fill data of my dropdownlist from controller (With Viewbag/ViewData) before the page loads because it would slow it down, but instead I'd like to **fill the DropDownList data on user click with a call to a controller function, and call the read method only once**(on first click). How would I be able to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set [autoBind](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-autoBind) property to false. It will cause that dropdown will not be filled by data before user click on it.
2. After component is initialized [dataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-dataBound) event is started so you can set readonly in it.

[Demo here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EYuQI)

Comment: Aha, that's close to what I need, but from the demo I realized I'd need not "readonly" but being able to choose normally values from the dropdown but without doing read each time. So I think I'd have to unbind the transport somehow and make dataSource local after first read?

Comment: Then point 1 is enough for you. Data will be stored in memory after first call. You can see that if you will comment dataBound event in demo, then press F12 and choose network. You can see there that after user clicks on dropdown there is called request to retrieve a data. After user click on it second time, this request is not called again. By default data are cached and read is called only once.

Comment: Oh wow, that's perfect. Would it work the same way if I put this dropdown within a grid as a foreign key column? I assume not since when you have a dropdownlist within a kendo grid the dropdown is recreated each time you click on the cell, therefore new read call is being made, correct?

Comment: I think it will works same even in grid. If you will want call read method and recreate dropdown you will have to explicitly call it.